# CSS - Margins on div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align vertical some text in a div here:
HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div11">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BrJSq87IMAAD3Zg.png" alt="" width="40px">
    </div>
    <div class="div12">
        <a href="">yo</a>
        </br>
        <a href="">yo</a>            
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    height: 40px;
}

.div1 div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.div12 {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mVPG/1/

The height of my divs is fixed so all I want to do is set up a padding-top on the last div (.div12) to move the text down a bit. However when I add a padding-top all the box are brought down.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: In your fiddle, there is a .div12 { margin-top: 30px; }. Why? Using the CSS of the question, the layout seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `inline-block`, each block acts as if it where text that gets alined (by default) on the baseline. If you increase the height of the second block, the baseline goes down, and the first block as well.

You can use `vertical-align: top` to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace CSS with this:

```
.div1 {
    height: 40px;
}

.div1 > div {
    float: left;
}

.div12 {
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
}
```

The `div1 div` selector also applies to all descendants so using > only applies to first one. Also if container is height fixed i think it's better to use float.

[JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVPG/2/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "`.div1 div {display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;}`" and there is no need for `.div12 { margin-top: 30px; }` since you want both aligned top and no extra space on top of "Text div"

Also, just for a better practice, avoid using "`<br>`" tag, there are many "Block" tag like, `<div>, <p>` etc. and if there are list of "links" use "`<ul><li>`" and you can control the margins and spaces with CSS.

Here is the updated code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div11">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BrJSq87IMAAD3Zg.png" alt="" width="40px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="div12">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">yo</a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="">yo</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1 {
    height: 40px;
}
.div1 div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.div12 ul,
.div12 li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Working Fiddle for the same: **http://jsfiddle.net/PK3UU/**

Hope this is helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ? `http://jsfiddle.net/4mVPG/4/` i cleaned up css a little bit

```
div {
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and for html

```
<div class="div11">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/40" alt="" width="40px" />
</div>
<div class="div12">
    <a href="">yo</a>
    <br />
    <a href="">yo</a>
</div>
```